# How to get a spinner from listView programmatically

Tags: android, listview

I've created a `Spinner` programmatically and add it to ListView's adapter. However, I can't get the `Spinner` back from `ListView`.

```
//listView = (NestedListView)findViewById(R.id.exListView);

create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Spinner spinner;

                for (int i=0; i<listView.getChildCount(); i++) {

                    if (listView.getChildAt(i) instanceof Spinner){
                        spinner = (Spinner) listView.getChildAt(i);
                        String selection = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();
                        Log.e("spinner device", selection);
                    }
                }
            }

});
```

My adapter

```
public class ExpListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    private ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> mGroups;
    private ArrayList<DeviceObject> deviceObList;
    private ArrayList<RoomSuggestion> roObjList;
    private Context mContext;

    public ExpListAdapter (Context context,ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> groups, ArrayList<DeviceObject> deviceObList, ArrayList<RoomSuggestion> roObjList){
        mContext = context;
        mGroups = groups;
        this.deviceObList = deviceObList;
        this.roObjList = roObjList;
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return mGroups.size();
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView,
                             ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.group_view, null);
        }

        if (isExpanded) {
            //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group раскрыта
        } else {
            //Изменяем что-нибудь, если текущая Group скрыта
        }

        Typeface lightFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "font/GothamProLight.ttf");

        TextView textGroup = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textGroup);

        textGroup.setTypeface(lightFace);
        textGroup.setText("Thereses gate 46");

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, final int childPosition, boolean isLastChild,
                             View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.child_view, null);
        }

        Typeface mediumFace = Typeface.createFromAsset(mContext.getAssets(), "font/GothamProMedium.ttf");

        TextView textChild = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textChild);
        textChild.setTypeface(mediumFace);
        textChild.setText( mGroups.get(groupPosition).get(childPosition) );

        RelativeLayout rl = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.bg_button_screen);

        if( !deviceObList.get(childPosition).getProduct_id().equals("0") ) {
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#4fcc54"));
        } else {
            rl.setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#e5910d"));
        }

        View linearLayoutG =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.container);
        LinearLayout.LayoutParams layoutParams = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
        layoutParams.setMargins(10, 0, 10, 30);
        linearLayoutG.setLayoutParams(layoutParams);

        RelativeLayout spinnerOpen = (RelativeLayout) convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerOpen);
        View linearLayout =  convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);

        ImageView imageS = (ImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerImage);
        imageS.getLayoutParams().width = 20;
        imageS.getLayoutParams().height = 20;
        imageS.setImageResource(R.drawable.spin_ok);

        ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
        for (int i=0; i<roObjList.size(); i++) {
            list.add(roObjList.get(i).getName() );
        }

        final Spinner spinner = new Spinner(mContext);
        // Make sure you have valid layout parameters.
        spinner.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT, 100));

        spinner.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.bg_spinner);

        ArrayAdapter spinnerArrayAdapter = new ArrayAdapter(mContext,
                    R.layout.spinner_item, list);
        spinner.setAdapter(spinnerArrayAdapter);

        // open spinner
        spinnerOpen.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                spinner.performClick();
            }
        });

        ((LinearLayout) linearLayout).addView(spinner);

        spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                Log.e("selected", String.valueOf(parent.getItemAtPosition(position)) );
                Log.e("childPosition", String.valueOf(childPosition));
            }
            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your question and your problem ?

Comment: You are not doing in right way see [Implementing CheckAll and UncheckAll for a listview in Android](http://wptrafficanalyzer.in/blog/implementing-checkall-and-uncheckall-for-a-listview-in-android/) example

Comment: @fxm question: Why my code dont work? And how get spinner value form listvView. Spinner i create in adapter programaticaly. 
problem: I cant get Spinner value

Comment: @ρяσѕρєяK  It is not what i need. I create spinner in adapter programaticaly and get value spinner from list view

Comment: @jikazali: your current implementation is not what actually u need. to achieve same as required following provided line and use Spinner instead of CheckBox.

Comment: place where you setting adapter and your adapter code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following code:

```
//listView = (NestedListView)findViewById(R.id.exListView);

create.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {

        for(int i = 0; i < listView.getAdapter().getCount(); i++ ) {

            for(int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++ ) {

                View _mainView = listView.getChildAt(i);

                LinearLayout _linearLayout = _mainView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);

                Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(0);

                String selection = (String) spinner.getSelectedItem();

                Log.e("spinner device", selection);

            }

        }

    }

});
```

Comment: Yeah I know that. After see your adapter I realized you do not use a `spinner` array. In your case, you should get the main view, then get the `LinearLayout` (`R.id.spinnerL`) and get the `spinner` from it.

Comment: Take a look in my edition and try to do something like that.

Comment: Thanks for answer, but i have error in this line `LinearLayout _linearLayout = (LinearLayout) _mainView.findViewById(R.id.spinnerL);` its `FATAL EXCEPTION: main java.lang.NullPointerException`

Comment: the `_mainView` is probably `null`. Make sure the `view` that come from `listView.getChildAt(i)`

Comment: This is `for(int i = 0; i < listView.getChildCount(); i++ )` or `for(int j = 0; j < listView.getChildCount(); j++ )` and then `listView.getChildAt(i)` ?

Comment: No, because they're the same. Debug your code and pay attention what kinda `view` come from `getChildAt(i)`. My answer was presuming that outcome from `listView.getChildAt(i)` was `R.layout.group_view`, but you must ensure what outcome is coming

Comment: thanks for your answers, my apps now down in line `Spinner spinner = (Spinner) _linearLayout.getChildAt(0);`

Comment: Wow great. Now you must ensure the outcome that comes from `_linearLayout.getChildAt(0)`. I was presuming that is the `spinner` because it's the only `view` you added into the `LinearLayout` in the adapter. But debug it as well and make sure if it's coming right